# Trouble with MSBuild Copy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task

Hi I have the following target.

```
<Target
  Name="TestCopy"
  AfterTargets="BeforeBuild"
    >

<Message
    Text="Copying base Sitecore config files @(GenerateDuringBuild) 

        %(GenerateDuringBuild.RootDir)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Directory)UpdatedConfiguration\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Extension)


        %(GenerateDuringBuild.RootDir)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Directory)UpdatedConfiguration\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Extension).test
      "

        />

 <Copy
    SourceFiles="%(GenerateDuringBuild.RootDir)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Directory)UpdatedConfiguration\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Extension)"
    DestinationFiles="%(GenerateDuringBuild.RootDir)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Directory)UpdatedConfiguration\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)\%(GenerateDuringBuild.Filename)%(GenerateDuringBuild.Extension).test"
    Condition="!Exists('%(GenerateDuringBuild.FullPath)')"
    />


</Target>
```

The Message outputs the correct paths but does not do the copy.

The file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong variable name. GenerateDuringBuild is for another task. Lesson Learned. Do not copy and paste.